# Factorial Showing already Running but not running in eclipse

Tags: java, for-loop, factorial

I am very beginner not having enough knowledge. When I am running factorial its showing already running but not asking for value or showing any error.

```
package loops;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);

int n = sc.nextInt();
 int factorial = 1;
 for(int i = n; i>=1; i--) {
 factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    System.out.println(factorial);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't "ask" for a value. It silently waits until you input a number.

Comment: This is because you have not entered any value. Voting to close as cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a print statement like, System.out.print("Enter the value:"), then you'll understand what's happening. If the statement doesn't shows up in the output, check that your ide is running fine.

Comment: Your program should be ideally asking for a value without any prompt and you must be missing that so I suggested to add one print statement.